# How to save multiple assertion failure result in CSV format in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, assertion

I have written script in JSR223 assertion and wanted to save multiple assertion failure result in CSV format. How this can be achieved in JMeter?

Below is the script

```
def responseJson = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())
def lastName = responseJson.data[0].last_name 
def email = responseJson.data[0].email
def firstName = responseJson.data[0].first_name
if (email != 'test') {
    def subResult = new org.apache.jmeter.assertions.AssertionResult()
    subResult.setFailure(true)
    subResult.setFailureMessage("Incorrect email value, Correct value is-->" + email) 
    prev.addAssertionResult(subResult)
} 
if (lastName != 'Lawson') { 
    def subResult = new org.apache.jmeter.assertions.AssertionResult() 
    subResult.setFailure(true) 
    subResult.setFailureMessage("Incorrect last name value, Correct value is-->" + lastName) 
    prev.addAssertionResult(subResult) 
} 
if (firstName != 'test') { 
    def subResult = new org.apache.jmeter.assertions.AssertionResult() 
    subResult.setFailure(true) 
    subResult.setFailureMessage("Incorrect first name value, Correct value is-->" + firstName) 
    prev.addAssertionResult(subResult)
}

else { 
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true) 
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("correct value") 
    prev.addAssertionResult(AssertionResult) 
} 

if (prev.getAssertionResults().findAll { result -> result.isFailure() }.size() > 0) {
    prev.setSuccessful(false)
}
```

Below is the JSON:

```
{ "per_page": 6, "total": 12, "data": [ { "last_name": "Lawson", "id": 7, "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/7-image.jpg", "first_name": "Michael", "email": "michael.lawson@reqres.in" }, { "last_name": "Ferguson", "id": 8, "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/8-image.jpg", "first_name": "Lindsay", "email": "lindsay.ferguson@reqres.in" }, { "last_name": "Funke", "id": 9, "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/9-image.jpg", "first_name": "Tobias", "email": "tobias.funke@reqres.in" }, { "last_name": "Fields", "id": 10, "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/10-image.jpg", "first_name": "Byron", "email": "byron.fields@reqres.in" }, { "last_name": "Edwards", "id": 11, "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/11-image.jpg", "first_name": "George", "email": "george.edwards@reqres.in" }, { "last_name": "Howell", "id": 12, "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/12-image.jpg", "first_name": "Rachel", "email": "rachel.howell@reqres.in" } ], "page": 2, "total_pages": 2, "support": { "text": "To keep ReqRes free, contributions towards server costs are appreciated!", "url": "https://reqres.in/#support-heading" } }
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. It'd be very helpful if you could expand your question with a code sample of your best effort to solve the problem so far.

Comment: Update my question with script and JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to store multiple [AssertionResults](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/assertions/AssertionResult.html) for the single sampler in the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) with the code "you have written", my expectation is that you will need to migrate to [SampleResult.addSubResult()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#addSubResult-org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult-) function, something like:

```
def responseJson = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())
def lastName = responseJson.data[0].last_name
def email = responseJson.data[0].email
if (email != 'test') {
    def subResult = new org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult()
    subResult.setSuccessful(false)
    subResult.setResponseMessage("Incorrect email value" + email)
    prev.addSubResult(subResult)
}
if (lastName != 'test') {
    def subResult = new org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult()
    subResult.setSuccessful(false)
    subResult.setResponseMessage("Incorrect lastName value" + email)
    prev.addSubResult(subResult)
} else {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("correct value")
    prev.addAssertionResult(AssertionResult)
}

if (prev.getSubResults().findAll { result -> !result.isSuccessful() }.size() > 0) {
    prev.setSuccessful(false)
}
```

More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)